# Squid Proxy Suddenly Inactive and Unable To Connect

Tags: ubuntu, squid

My laboratory is running the squid proxy server. Sometime the proxy is unable to connect while the proxy IP is still can be ping. What i think is that the squid is switch to stop working, but when i check with

```
ps -ax
```

the service of proxy is running well. Yet the response from browser reporting that it is unable to connect. Then i check the running port with nmap -- if i'am right -- i cannot see the squid port (said that it was running on port 3128). I restart the squid service and it still won't working.

What i miss here? or is there something i should check?